# A problem related to orthogonal matrix and positive inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question given by the professor in a linear algebra class, and I have no idea how to prove it.

let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be nonzero n-dimensional vector with $\alpha^{T}\beta>0$. Prove that there exists a orthogonal matrix $A$, which holds that $(A\alpha)_i(A\beta)_i>0$, for $1<=i<=n$.

Comment: Has the professor given approval to asking for help on the internet?

Comment: Yes, since it’s not our homework, just a problem for thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is strictly less than $\pi/2$. In the plane spanned by the vectors $u = e_1$ and $v = e_2+\ldots+e_n$, choose two directions $a,b$ that form angles $\pm \theta/2$ from the direction of the bisector $u/||u|| + v/||v||$ and rotate the pair of vectors $\alpha,\beta$ in such a manner that they end up collinear to $a,b$. Then, the rotated vectors will have all coordinates positive.